# how get radio button value in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good day to everyone.

I'm having a problem how to get a value of my radio button using javascript.
Here is the html code.

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" value="male"> Male</label>
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" value="female"> Female</label>
```

and my script goes this way.

```
<script>
 function submit_member(){
    $.post('<?php echo site_url('admin/submit'); ?>',
         {
            gender            : $('#gender').val()
         },
         function(data){
              if(data.result=='SUCCESS'){
                $('#gender').val('');
              }
        },'json'
         );
  }
</script>
```

for other value like my firstname and lastname field I was able to get the value. Can anybody give me a sample code how to get a selected gender.

Comment: You cannot assign the same ID for two objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**IDs must be unique;** ID selector returns the first matching element that has the specified ID. You should use classes instead. Since the target elements are radio `input`s you also can use the [`Attribute Equals Selector`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) for selecting the target inputs, and [`:checked`](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) selector for filtering the checked input:

```
$('input[name=gender]:checked').val();
```

Comment: both ThiefMaster and you got the same result :) Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can't have the same ID for two elements, but you can access the radiobutton "group" by its name with plain javascript:

```
var rbVal = document.querySelector("input[name='gender']:checked").value;
```

jQuery:

```
var rbVal = $("input[name='gender']:checked").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#gender option:selected').val();
```

Comment: thanks buddy!  my problem solve. I just remove the ; and it works fine :) thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Question was asking about javascript, not using jQuery.

You don't need unique IDs really. Here's a solution using just JS. Obviously you may need to change some selector stuff around...

```
<fieldset>
  <input type="radio" name="someName" value="value1" checked="true" />
  <input type="radio" name="someName" value="value2" />
</fieldset>
```

And the JS:

```
console.log(document.getElementsByName('someName')[0].value);
```

Here is the JSBin: http://jsbin.com/jeracaragisa/2/edit?html,js,console

Answer (score -2):

```
document.getElementById("gender").value
```